# LINQ performance improvements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq

I'm starting to use LINQ, and I'm very happy with its intuitive use, but I'm the kind of person who thinks performance can always be improved.

What's the best way of self analyzing LINQ?  Is there a tool within Visual Studio 2010 that will help me analyze my LINQ?  Any type of query analyzer, something that will give me accurate numbers so I can see if I'm really improving times.

What's the methods you use for improving performance for LINQ?

Comment: Which flavor are you talking about? LINQ over in-memory objects or LINQ over Expression trees (such as LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework)?

Comment: More specifically LINQ to SQL.  But I thought the purpose of LINQ is to help generalise data access, so no matter if you're just reading from XML vs reading from an SQL database, you could use the same methodology?

Comment: @Fritos: Different LINQ providers will decide what to do with the expression trees in different ways. LINQ to objects is the most straightforward, but LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-XML will have various different performance gotchas based on how they independently decide what to do with the "query".

Comment: @Ocelot20, Interesting... Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is your friend.